# Blank Page on Android 4.x loading Angular 5 SPA

Tags: android, angular, polyfills

I am developing an SPA which works perfect on every browser, except Android native below 4.4 Kit Kat (not included) which shows a blank page. I had uncommented the polyfills of polyfills.ts (Angular CLI), tried to install `npm core-js`and added `import 'core-js/es7';`and `import 'core-js/es6';` to polyfills.ts file:

```
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

import 'core-js/es6';
import 'core-js/es7';

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';


/**
 * Required to support Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox and Opera. http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation
 **/import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
import 'web-animations-js';
```

I cant get it working in any android device below 4.4 Kit Kat. I had also set angular-cli.json just to test if I could get it begin working:

```
  "scripts": [ 
    "../node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js",
    "../node_modules/core-js/client/core.min.js"
  ],
```

Nothing seems to work. how could I know what component is not supported by Android 4.3 WebView and below?

Thanks in advance

Dependencies in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.104",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.2",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "grunt": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
```

Comment: [Supported versions](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#browser-support). Anyway, would you debug your `android browser` via chrome and get console error ? It would be easier for you to detect this error. When you will have exact error then you will see if polyfills are enough to run Angular on browsers which has version below `Kitkat 4.4`.

Comment: I had already read the Android.io documentation, it says that es6 is mandatory for android 4.1+ (As you see I have imported that polyfill). My problem here is that I cannot inspect nor debug Android Native browser (Chrome detects no browser).

Comment: I managed to solve myself, thanks a lot

Comment: How you resolved it ?

Comment: I am writing the answer, see it below in a few moments

Answer (score 1):

In WebView corresponding Android 4.3 and below we need to add polyfills to angular cli scripts tag. For some kind of reason I cannot get to understand, polyfills.ts file dont adds the corresponding.

I realized this changing the Android code for the WebView:

1. You need to set a new ChromeClient
2. Set this code on the custom ChromeClient class:

   public void onConsoleMessage(String message, int lineNumber, String sourceID) {
       Log.d("MyApplication", message + " -- From line "
               + lineNumber + " of "
               + sourceID);
   }
3. Now your Run console in Android studio will print console warnings, errors, and the rest. There you can know which polyfills you need.

**Correction for polyfills**

First of all add the files to angular-cli.json:

```
  "scripts": [ 
    "../node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js",
    "../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js",
    "../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js",
    "../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js",
    "../node_modules/web-animations-js/web-animations.min.js",
    "../node_modules/web-animations-js/web-animations-next.min.js",
    "../node_modules/classlist.js/classList.min.js"
  ],
```

Second you have to install the libraries:

- `npm install --save core-js`
- `npm install --save systemjs`
- `npm install --save web-animations`
- `npm install --save classlist.js`

Third:

- Uncomment all the polyfills on the `polyfills.ts` file.
- Add: `import 'core-js/es6/promise';`

This is how you could support android 4.3 and below webviews with polyfills.

**IMPORTANT:** Althought I have imported the WebView polyfill for animations, Android cant manage css generated by animations, so better you disable this animations if you wanna have a correct behavior. Things got broken.